# How can i loop foam on the ocean modifier in blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, node-editor, ocean-simulation

for a while I have been trying to make a seamlessly looping ocean modifier animation and as far as the geometry goes I have a perfect loop, however, I have not been able to seamlessly loop the generated foam and I was wondering if there was an easy workaround for this [image: I have attached my nodes and current textures below] I'd appreciate any help I can get as I am stumped on where to proceed, thanks in advance to all those who can surrender some time.